# Jenkins: Changing default log files location in windows

Tags: jenkins

I need to change the location of log files of jenkins outside of jenkins home(installation) directory. I checked in jenkins.xml file but did not found any parameter to set.

Gone through some articles but they suggest to create symlinks.

Please let suggest if anyone already did it.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the log location by changing the default location for the logs in `%JENKINS_HOME%/jenkins.xml`. By default the logs get stored at `%JENKINS_HOME%/jenkins.out` and `%JENKINS_HOME%/jenkins.err`.

Comment: I know some parameter need to set, but which parameter need to set in jenkins.xml ?

Comment: Change the value of `JENKINS_LOG`

Comment: `<service>
  <id>Jenkins</id>
  <name>Jenkins</name>
  <description>This service runs Jenkins continuous integration system.</description>
  <env name="JENKINS_HOME" value="%BASE%"/>
  
  <executable>%BASE%\jre\bin\java</executable>
  <arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=443 --webroot="%BASE%\war" -Dhttp.auth.preference="basic" </arguments>
  
  <logmode>rotate</logmode>

  <onfailure action="restart" />
</service>`  Copying it to notepad or notepad++ would give ease to read.

Comment: Can you clarify? Adding <env name="JENKINS_LOG" value="/path/to/logs"/> in jenkins.xml seems to have no effect.